# JPA 2 Entity Bean primary Key Required?

Tags: netbeans, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to create an entity bean but Netbeans IDE complains Entity Bean cannot be generated because there is no primary key so I want to know if a primary key is required by every Entity Bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, the primary key is mandatory